# Extract execution plan in XML format to table

Tags: sql-server, xml, extract, structure, sql-execution-plan

I'm trying to extract the data from SQL server execution plans in a generic way.

As an example the execution plan for

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.all_objects o1
```

as shown in SSMS is below

[image]

The UI shows nodes along with costs for each node and percentages. How can I extract this from the underlying XML into a table structure?

I've tried to query the XML by my self, but it seems that the XML structure is changing from query to query.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: What are you planning to do with that data? This may help us guide you in the right direction. What is your table structure?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started ([DB Fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/hq66aIte)).

```
DECLARE @X XML = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><ShowPlanXML ...';
        
DECLARE @Nodes TABLE
  (
     PlanId                    INT,
     NodeId                    INT,
     PhysicalOp                VARCHAR(200),
     EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost FLOAT,
     EstimatedOperatorCost     FLOAT,
     ParentNodeId              INT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(PlanId, NodeId)
  ); 
 
WITH  XMLNAMESPACES (default 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan'),
plans AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by qp) as PlanId, qp.query('.') as plan_xml
FROM @X.nodes('//QueryPlan') n(qp)
)
INSERT @Nodes(PlanId, NodeId, PhysicalOp, EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost, ParentNodeId) 
SELECT PlanId, 
       NodeId = relop.value('@NodeId', 'int'), 
       PhysicalOp = relop.value('@PhysicalOp', 'varchar(200)'), 
       EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost = relop.value('@EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost', 'float'),
       /*XPath ancestor axis not supported so just go up a few levels and look for the closest ancestor Relop*/
       ParentNodeId = COALESCE(
       relop.value('..[local-name() = "RelOp"]/@NodeId', 'int'),
       relop.value('../..[local-name() = "RelOp"]/@NodeId', 'int'),
       relop.value('../../..[local-name() = "RelOp"]/@NodeId', 'int'),
       relop.value('../../../..[local-name() = "RelOp"]/@NodeId', 'int')
       )
FROM plans
CROSS APPLY plan_xml.nodes('//RelOp') n(relop);

UPDATE N1
SET EstimatedOperatorCost = EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost -  ISNULL((SELECT SUM(EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost) FROM @Nodes N2 WHERE N1.PlanId = N2.PlanId AND N2.ParentNodeId = N1.NodeId),0)
FROM @Nodes N1


SELECT *,
       EstPctOperatorCost = FORMAT(EstimatedOperatorCost/MAX(EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost) OVER (PARTITION BY PlanId), 'P0')
FROM @Nodes
```

The execution plan is a tree - there are likely more elegant ways of getting the parent operator than my attempt!

The above is not battle tested across a sample size of more than two execution plans so you may well encounter issues with it that you will need to fix.

You can visit the URI http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan to see information about the various schemas though for some reason I've never got to the bottom of it displays "The request is blocked." for me unless I use incognito mode.

Comment: This will help me, thanks, is it possible to get the result by percentage of cost? As it is shown in the graphic display?

Comment: @Elim - Yeah that is trickier as the EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost is for the entire sub tree, to get the per operator costs each operator needs to subtract the costs for its immediate children. So within a plan you would either need to find the root node (`//RelOp[@NodeId = "0"]'` and then work down through its descendants. Or just find all Relops as this query does and then navigate up to find their closest Relop ancestor)

Comment: Maybe it is possible to calculate from the result the relativity between the values and convert them to percentages?

Comment: @Elim - Answer edited to do that. By the way the estimated costs are TBH not very useful - I hardly ever look at them. Much more useful is the "per operator" timings in actual execution plans as they show where time is *really* being spent. The estimated costings may be fine for the majority of plans but in "problem" plans - which is where the majority of query tuning time is spent often the problem parts are given low plan costings (which is often why that problem plan was chosen in the first place)

Comment: But if I understand correctly, the time for each operator is not in the XML either, right?

Comment: It is in the XML for an "actual" execution plan. In the `RunTimeInformation` element